# How do I get my webcam to work

Tags: webcam

I downloaded ubuntu over the weekend replacing Windows Vista and so far everything has been fantastic, except for one thing.  I cannot get my webcam to work.  I've tried camorama and camera monitor but they can't load an image.  Can anyone help with any apps that I can download?

Many thanks

Updated 23/8/10:
I have two webcams that I can use - a Microsoft Lifecam VX-3000 and a Trust WB-1400T webcam.
I have downloaded 'Cheese Webcam Booth', 'Camorama Webcam Viewer' and 'Kamoso'.  I have read that there are a lot of problems using the MS Lifecam with Linux so any recommendations on webcams which work particularly well with Ubuntu would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of webcam do you have?

Comment: Like txwikinger asked - what kind of camera is it - is it embedded in a laptop or standalone?

Answer (score 2):

We need the make and model to really help you but you can look at the official support list here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsMultimediaWebCameras (note: some reports might be outdated)

If your webcam doesn't show there, [edit your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/2888/edit), telling us what the webcam is.

Answer (score 1):

webcams that are **ordinary** no HD will work fine "my webcam is a creative webcam Vista" a very old one and the system detects it in a second.. in my experience webcams are the most annoying hardware to be used with linux there only a limited list of webcams that work FINE on linux and the others will give u headaches in installing then they'll be too dark.

here's a list of the most supported webcams,digicams on linux maybe it'll help u:

[Linux-drivers supported webcams and digicams list](http://www.linux-drivers.org/usb_webcams.html)